# Jemand, der hingerichtet werden soll

Tags: single-word-request, noun

Gibt es ein Substantiv für jemanden, der hingerichtet werden soll? Also der Hingerichtete vor seiner Hinrichtung.

Comment: Mir fällt nur *der Zum Tode verurteilte* ein.  Und das Netz bestätigt einiger massen, zB https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kategorie:Zum_Tode_verurteilte_Person.

Comment: Der *Hinzurichtende*? *Todeszelleninsasse*? *Todeskandidat*? Oder etwas unschärfer: *Delinquent*?

Comment: *Galgenmännchen*, *Galgenschwengel* usw gibt es auch, aber alle werden seit langem eher figurativ verstanden.

Comment: "Welche Mordskulisse, wird manch öffentlich Hinzurichtender angesichts der vielen Schaulustigen gemurmelt haben." (Martin Gerhard)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wenn über die Todesstrafe berichtet wird, geschieht das meist über:

> Todeskandidat

Aber ich finde

> Todgeweihter

auch schön und passt auch darauf, ebenso wie das Beispiel aus den Kommentaren:

> Hinzurichtender

Comment: _Todeskanditat_ finde ich etwas respektlos, _Todgeweihter_ zu religiös, aber _Hinzurichtender_ trifft es eigentlich genau. Hätte mir eigentlich selber einfallen müssen. ;-)

Comment: @ceving I find Hinzurichtender zu bürokratendeutsch, wenn du mich fragst. Natürlich sehr spezifisch, aber zu sehr auf das Verfahren fokussiert.

Answer (score 1):

In deutschsprachigen Ländern gibt es seit einigen Jahrzehnten keine Todesstrafe mehr. Seit Ende der Nürnberger Prozesse gab es kaum noch Anlässe, lokal über entsprechend Verurteilte zu sprechen. (In der DDR war es m.W. weitgehend Tabuthema.) Daher ist der aktuelle Gebrauch in Umgangssprache und Medien wahrscheinlich von anderen Sprachen und Kulturen sowie diversen Fachsprachen beeinflusst.

Traditionell gibt es allerdings viele Begriffe aus dem Themenfeld, die eine morphologische Ableitung ermöglichen würden. Dem Deutschen fehlt dazu eine regelmäßige Opposition von Substantivendungen wie im englischen *-er* und *-ee* (und *-ed*). Stattdessen muss man meist den (stilistisch unschönen) Umweg über substantivierte Partizipien nehmen:

- *Hinrichtung, hinrichten* → *der/die *Hinzurichtende*
- *Exekution, exekutieren* → *der/die *Zuexekutierende*
- *Henker, henken* (oft verwechselt mit *hängen*) → *der/die *Zuhenkende*
- *Scharfrichter* → *der/die *Scharfzurichtende*
- *Todesstrafe* → *der *Todessträfling / die *Todessträfine*
- *Todesurteil* → *der/die *Zumtodeverurteilte / *Todesverurteilte*
- *Kapitalverbrechen* → *der Kapitalverbrecher / die Kapitalverbrecherin*

Mal von den Problemen der Rechtschreibung nominalisitierter mehrgliedriger Partizipien abgesehen, wird (gefühlt) derzeit am ehesten *der/die zum Tode Verurteilte* verwendet. *Todessträfling* ist vielleicht der stilistisch schönste Begriff, aber meiner Einschätzung nach ziemlich unüblich – angesichts des geringen Frauenanteils ist die schwierige Movierung von *+ling* ein vernachlässigbares Problem.

Wer wegen eines Deliktes, auf das die Todesstrafe (engl.: *capital punishment*) steht, überführt und verurteilt wurde, dem „kostet es den Kopf“ (lat. *caput*). Das entsprechende *Kapitalverbrechen* wird heutzutage aber häufig mit laxerer Bedeutung gebraucht oder als *Finanzvergehen* missverstanden. Darum ist *Kapitalverbrecher* kein geeigneter Begriff für den gesuchten Kontext.

Zum Latinismus *Exekution* ließe sich auch direkt – statt über den Umweg *exektuieren* – ein Partizip und somit wahrscheinlich **Exekutand* oder **Exekutent* bilden. (Mein Latein ist arg eingerostet.) Diese Wörter sind aber noch ungebräuchlicher als **Exekutor*.

Während in totalitären Regimen, die fast immer die Todesstrafe einsetzen, oft nur wenig Zeit zwischen Urteil und Vollzug vergeht, werden in verfassten Rechtsstaaten normalerweise sämtliche juristische Möglichkeiten (Revisionen, Gnadengesuche, …) ausgeschöpft, was häufig zu einer langen Haftzeit vor der Exekution und manchmal zu einer Abwendung oder Umwandlung der Strafe führt. Da in einem Gefängnis – Rechtssprech: *Justizvollzugsanstalt* – meist ein eigener Bereich für die zur Höchsstrafe verurteilten Insassen vorgesehen ist, haben sich eigene Begriffe eingebürgert. Das englische *death row inmate* würde ich bspw. als ***Todestrakthäftling*** oder wie @guidot als *Todeszelleninsasse* übersetzen. Je nach Kontext dürften das die passendsten Begriffe sein.

*Todeskandidat* ist zwar nicht unüblich, würde ich aber vermeiden, da es auch bspw. in medizinischen Kontexten verwendet werden könnte.

In Medienberichten wird häufig auch der Grund für die Verurteilung als Bezeichnung für die Person verwendet, etwa: *der verurteilte Polizistenmörder, mutmaßliche Massenvergewaltiger, ehemalige Drogenschmuggler, feindliche Kämpfer, sowjetische Spion*.

Comment: Grundsätzlich gute Antwort, aber über die substantivierten Partizipien mit *Zu-* bin ich mir unsicher; ich denke nicht, dass diese Formen so grammatikalisch sind.